London travel options
I have a 3 day trip to London planned in Nov. Flying into Gatwick and staying near Waterloo station. 2 adults and 3 kids under 5 years old. We will travel around the city using tube and bus. I'm wondering what is the simplist and best value option to do this. I think the 3 kids go free?
Thanks for your suggestions...

What has your research so far revealed?

Simplest and best value are not necessarily the same. Simplest is to use your contactless debit or credit card. But whether it’s best value depends on what fees and rates your card issuer applies, and your actual travel patterns. A PAYG Oyster Card is probably the only worthwhile alternative.

AFAIK if you pay with a contactless card, the TfL system automatically applies a daily price cap for each adult, and the kids travel free.

Thanks for your answers. Research so far is train to Waterloo from Gatwick will cost about £75 return. 3 day travel card for zones 1-4 is about £95. So £170 total for the 3 days. Does the daily price cap come in under £30 per adult? If so that should be cheaper option as long as the kids are free for all trips

The pay-as-you-go price caps are shown here

thank you for the help

What time do you arrive/depart London? Is your trip 3 days in total including travel from/to Waterloo on arrival /departure, or 3 days plus travel? If the former, quite a lot of your time will taken up just getting around from place to place. You’ll need to plan any sightseeing carefully to avoid seeing a lot of the inside of buses/the underground and not a lot of the city.

You don't need a zone 1-4 travel card if staying near Waterloo. Most touristy stuff is in zone 1

@Traveller, arrive in Gatwick ay 9.30am day 1 and plan to stay quite close to the hotel in Waterloo for whats left of the day. Day 3 we leave for Gatwick around 3.30pm. I'll plan out the days to minimise time spent on transport and q's for attractions as the kids are quite young so wont want that. thanks for the post

@Marianne013 thanks, checked out the zones and most likely will be within zone 1 for most of the trip. appreciate the message

You need to research what you want to do, and how far you'd be willing to go to use public transport. I used to have to travel across London on business trips (in through Kings Cross, out through Waterloo) in order to get from one train station to the other. Rather than take the tube, I discovered I could walk it in about 45 minutes - but that was just me on my own.

I just did a short trip to London from the US.  Flew into Gatwick, transferred in London and stayed along the Jubilee line (Stratford).
Here are the reasons for my advice:

London is expensive.  If you are looking to pinch pennies, this is the wrong place to visit.
Your time is short.  Spending a few extra £ is worth not standing in line.
Its also a crowded city without much separation between tourist areas and people living in London. I live in Orlando and the wife and I rarely run into tourists when we commute to our work.

Advice:
Forget the Oyster/travel card.  You have to plan it perfectly to actually save money. To do so you will also have to wait in long lines. Instead skip the lines and use your credit card or Apple/Google pay. You and your wife will need a separate payment source.
Make sure that payment source does not have foreign transaction fees.
With this, you scan your card/phone on the gate in, and scan it on the way out. No waiting in line other than perhaps a short line at the gate during the most crowded of times. If you go over the daily limit, their IT is smart enough to only charge you up to the limit.
When we arrived at Gatwick the line for the Oyster card was at least an hour long. Instead we passed right through the gate and were on the platform as fast as our legs would carry us. The thought of waiting over an hour, in a small space with children after a flight is a horrible way to start a vacation.
I cannot comment on how to work the train system with children. I am sure there are plenty of youtube videos to do such.
You can save far more money by simply doing "take away" dining.  That is you get your meals to go and eat them elsewhere.  Just about every place charges for dining in.
Be prepared for bad weather, we visited in July and it rained every day. So even "take away" dining did not work for us.
The most economical meal we found was a place called The Pantry Cafe in Stratford. Not fancy, but the owner was really nice and there was plenty of good food for the money. While very inexpensive for London, it was rather pricey compared to the US.
The key takeaway is London is not cheap.

Pete, thanks for the detailed notes. I dont plan to stand in too many lines simply as the kids wont do it! We'll plan to see some attractions which dont require waiting round where possible. i hear you about the dining, expensive indeed. we'll do breakfast and lunch on a budget and accept dinner will burn a hole in the pocket!

From comments i've read about tube tickets, seems your suggestion is popular to PAYG. good to know the IT is smart enough to apply the daily cap, was unsure how that would work thanks. im coming from Ireland, so should cope if it rains! thanks so much!

@Ciaran I highly recommend the tower of London with the kids.  They can run around quite a bit, and there are interesting things to see.  About the only attraction that is crowded is the crown jewels and if you go early or late, the line is not bad at all.  For history buffs, the on site guards museum has a captured French eagle.

On buses, you scan in but not out (a standard fare unrelated to distance)
